# Not getting enough test coverage for schedulable batchable class

Tags: apex, unit-test, schedulebatch

I'm updating some code written by another developer, and I'm having a problem getting adequate code coverage for the batchable, schedulable class.

None of the test methods call execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List scope), and I can't figure out how to get it called.

Here's the class:

```
global class PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {
global List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList = new List<PriceBookEntry>();

// obtain all non-USD Item detail records
// Changed query string from Item Detail to Price Book Entry
global String queryString = 'SELECT Product2Id, Product2.Global_List_Price__c, CurrencyIsoCode FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id != null AND CurrencyIsoCode !=\'USD\' AND Product2.Global_List_Price__c > 0 ';
global List<CurrencyType> activeCurrencyList = new List<CurrencyType>();
global Map<Id, List<PricebookEntry>> itemIdToPriceBookEntryMap = new Map<Id, List<PricebookEntry>>();
global Map<String, CurrencyType> currencyCodeToTypeRecordMap = new Map<String, CurrencyType>();
global Id standardPriceBookId;
    
global PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate(){
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        standardPriceBookId = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricebook2 WHERE Name = 'Standard Price Book'].Id;    
    }
    else{
        standardPriceBookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    }
    
    
    activeCurrencyList = [  SELECT ConversionRate, IsoCode, DecimalPlaces, IsActive
                            FROM CurrencyType
                            WHERE IsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    
    // if no active currencies exist apart from USD, no need to process any records. Proceed with 'else' condition and pass a query string which will retrieve zero records.        
    if(!activeCurrencyList.isEmpty() && String.isNotBlank(String.valueOf(standardPriceBookId))){
        for(CurrencyType type : activeCurrencyList){
            currencyCodeToTypeRecordMap.put(type.IsoCode, type);
            //checkHeapSize('currency for loop');
        }    
        
        System.debug('currencyCode ' + currencyCodeToTypeRecordMap);
       
    }
    else{
        queryString = 'SELECT Id FROM PricebookEntry LIMIT 0';
    }
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<PricebookEntry> scope){
    System.debug('activeCurrencyList' + activeCurrencyList);
    //System.debug('itemIdToPriceBookEntryMap' + itemIdToPriceBookEntryMap);
    System.debug('currencyCodeToTypeRecordMap' + currencyCodeToTypeRecordMap);
    System.debug('standardPriceBookId' + standardPriceBookId);
    //List<PricebookEntry> createRecordsList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    List<PricebookEntry> updateRecordsList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    Set<String> currencyCodeSet = new Set<String>();
    //Map<Id, List<ItemDetailWrapper>> itemIdToDetailRecordMap = new Map<Id, List<ItemDetailWrapper>>();
    
    for(PricebookEntry pbe : scope){
        Decimal conversionRate = currencyCodeToTypeRecordMap.get(pbe.CurrencyIsoCode).ConversionRate;
        Decimal newPrice = pbe.Product2.Global_List_Price__c * conversionRate;
        pbe.UnitPrice = newPrice.setScale(2);
        updateRecordsList.add(pbe);
    }

    System.debug(updateRecordsList);           
    //System.debug(createRecordsList);
         
    
    // update Pricebook entry records 
    if(!updateRecordsList.isEmpty()){
        update updateRecordsList;
    }        
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    Database.executeBatch(this);
}

}
```

And here is the test class:

```
@isTest
public class PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate_Test {
private static Integer numProductsToCreate = 5;
private static Decimal listPrice = 1200;
private static Decimal conversionRateCAD = [    SELECT ConversionRate, IsoCode, DecimalPlaces, IsActive
                                                FROM CurrencyType
                                                WHERE IsoCode = 'CAD'].ConversionRate;
@testSetup
static void setup(){                
    List<Product2> productsToInsert = new List<Product2>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<numProductsToCreate;i++){
        Product2 testProd = new Product2(
            Name = 'testProduct-' + i,
            Part_Number__c = String.valueOf(i),
            Global_List_Price__c = listPrice,
            Product_Code__c = '10000',
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
            Item_State__c = 'WH-REC'
        );
        testProd = (Product2)TestFactory.createSObject(testProd);
        productsToInsert.add(testProd);            
    }       
    insert productsToInsert;
    
    ERP_Company__c test_ERPCompany = new ERP_Company__c(
        Name = 'testERPCompany'
    );
    test_ERPCompany = (ERP_Company__c)TestFactory.createSObject(test_ERPCompany);
    insert test_ERPCompany;
    
    List<Product_Company_Detail__c> itemDetailsToInsert = new List<Product_Company_Detail__c>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<numProductsToCreate;i++){
        Product_Company_Detail__c testDetail = new Product_Company_Detail__c(
            Product__c = productsToInsert[i].Id,
            ERP_Company__c = test_ERPCompany.Id,
            Item_Number__c = String.valueOf(i),
            CurrencyIsoCode = 'CAD'
        );
        testDetail = (Product_Company_Detail__c)TestFactory.createSObject(testDetail);
        itemDetailsToInsert.add(testDetail);            
    }       
    insert itemDetailsToInsert;

    List<PricebookEntry> pbeToInsert = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    
   
    
    List<CurrencyType> activeCurrencyList = [   SELECT ConversionRate, IsoCode, DecimalPlaces, IsActive
                                                FROM CurrencyType
                                                WHERE IsoCode = 'CAD'];
    

    
    System.debug('activeCurrencyList>' + activeCurrencyList);
    
    
    Id standardPriceBookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
           
}

// tests whether the pricebook entry is updated when the global list price of the Products is changed
@isTest
static void test_UpdateWhenListPriceChanges() {
    System.debug('conv: ' + conversionRateCAD);
    System.debug('listPrice: ' + listPrice);
    listPrice = 1500;
    
    List<Product2> productsToUpdate = [SELECT Name, Global_List_Price__c
                                      FROM Product2];
    
    for(Product2 prod : productsToUpdate){
        prod.Global_List_Price__c = listPrice;
    }
    
    update productsToUpdate;
    
    Decimal rawCurrencyConversion = conversionRateCAD * listPrice;
    Decimal newPriceBookEntryPrice = rawCurrencyConversion.setScale(2);
    
    Test.startTest();               
    PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate batchObj = new PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj);       
    Test.stopTest();
    
    List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList = [ SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, IsActive, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice 
                                                FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                WHERE CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    
    
    for(PriceBookEntry entry : pricebookEntryList){
        Decimal actualPrice = entry.UnitPrice.setScale(2);
        System.assertEquals(newPriceBookEntryPrice, actualPrice);           
    }
    
}


// tests whether the pricebook entry is updated accurately when the global list price of the Products is not in USD
@isTest
static void test_UpdateWhenListPriceNotInUSD() {
    List<Product2> productsToUpdate = [SELECT Name, Global_List_Price__c, CurrencyIsoCode
                                      FROM Product2];
    
    for(Product2 prod : productsToUpdate){
        prod.CurrencyIsoCode = 'CAD';
    }
    
    update productsToUpdate;
    System.debug('productsToUpdate>' + [SELECT Name, Global_List_Price__c, CurrencyIsoCode
                                      FROM Product2]);
    
    // since the product list price is in CAD, the updated PriceBookEntry price will be the same as the List Price
    Decimal newPriceBookEntryPrice = listPrice;
    
    Test.startTest();               
    PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate batchObj = new PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj);       
    Test.stopTest();
    
    List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList = [ SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, IsActive, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice 
                                                FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                WHERE CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    System.debug('pricebookEntryList>' + pricebookEntryList);
    
    for(PriceBookEntry entry : pricebookEntryList){
        System.assertEquals(newPriceBookEntryPrice, entry.UnitPrice);           
    }
}

// tests whether the pricebook entry is created when it is not present
@isTest
static void test_CreatePriceBookEntry() {
    List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList_ToDelete = [SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, IsActive, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice 
                                                        FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                        WHERE CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    delete pricebookEntryList_ToDelete;
           
    
    Test.startTest();               
    PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate batchObj = new PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj);       
    Test.stopTest();
    
    Decimal newPriceBookEntryPrice = conversionRateCAD * listPrice;
    
    List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList = [ SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, IsActive, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice 
                                                FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                WHERE CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    //System.assertEquals(numProductsToCreate, pricebookEntryList.size());
    
    for(PriceBookEntry entry : pricebookEntryList){
        System.assertEquals(newPriceBookEntryPrice, entry.UnitPrice);           
    }
    
}

// tests whether an extra pricebook entry is created or not if an already existent one is present but inactive
@isTest
static void test_UpdatePriceBookEntryToActive() {
    List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList_ToUpdate = [SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, IsActive, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice 
                                                        FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                        WHERE CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    for(PriceBookEntry pbe : pricebookEntryList_ToUpdate){
        pbe.IsActive = false;
    }
    
    update pricebookEntryList_ToUpdate;
    
    Test.startTest();               
    PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate batchObj = new PricebookEntryCurrencyUpdate();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(batchObj);       
    Test.stopTest();
    
    List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList = [ SELECT CurrencyIsoCode, IsActive, Name, Pricebook2Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice 
                                                FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                WHERE CurrencyIsoCode != 'USD'];
    
    // checks whether new entries are not created
    //System.assertEquals(numProductsToCreate, pricebookEntryList.size());
    
    //checks whether all entries have been activated
    for(PriceBookEntry entry : pricebookEntryList){
        System.assertEquals(true, entry.IsActive);           
    }
    
}

}
```

I realize the test class is a little redundant given the changes I've made to the code, but the code coverage is only 52% right now because execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List scope) is not covered by any of the tests. How can I update the test class to test this method?

Comment: Does the queryLocator find any records when the batch kicks off? If it doesn't, that would be my guess as to why the coverage is so low. Add a debug to see if any values are found when the batch executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the start method returns no sobjects to execute.
On this line

```
global String queryString = 'SELECT Product2Id, Product2.Global_List_Price__c, CurrencyIsoCode FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id != null AND CurrencyIsoCode !=\'USD\' AND Product2.Global_List_Price__c > 0 ';
```

is defined the query used. So the `start` method should return a list of `PriceBookEntry`, but nowhere in your test class is any of those price books created.

So to achieve coverage of the `execute` method insert in your setup at least one `PriceBookEntry` with correct data to match the query `where` filter. Something like this.

```
insert new PriceBookEntry(
    Product2Id = product.Id, CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR', Product2.Global_List_Price__c = 3
);
```